# what is the basis for the development of the following product

Tags: probability, products, characteristic-functions

I have the following identity in my probability text book, but I was unable to relate it to a known development. Here, $A_n$ is a series of events.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you expand the product, there are $2^n$ terms.  The first one arises from taking the $1$ in each binomial factor $1 - 1_{A_k}$, yielding $1^n=1$.  Each of the other $2^n-1$ terms corresponds to a nonempty subset $S \subseteq \{1,2,\dots,n\}$.  Note that the product of characteristic functions is the characteristic function of the intersection: $1_{A} 1_{B} = 1_{A \cap B}$.

Putting it all together:
\begin{align}
\prod_{j=1}^n \left(1 - 1_{A_j}\right)
&= \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}} \prod_{s \in S} \left(-1_{A_s}\right) \\
&= \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}} (-1)^{|S|} \prod_{s \in S} 1_{A_s} \\
&= \sum_{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}} (-1)^{|S|} 1_{A_{\prod_{s \in S}}} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\substack{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}:\\ |S|=k}} (-1)^k 1_{A_{\prod_{s \in S}}} \\
&= 1 + \sum_{k=1}^n  (-1)^k \sum_{\substack{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}:\\ |S|=k}} 1_{A_{\prod_{s \in S}}} \\
&= 1 - \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k-1} \sum_{\substack{S \subseteq \{1,\dots,n\}:\\ |S|=k}} 1_{A_{\prod_{s \in S}}} \\
\end{align}

This is a generalization of the binomial theorem
$$\prod_{j=1}^n (1-x) = (1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} (-1)^k x^k.$$